# System.Windows.Forms reference on vs.net 2013 express

Tags: c#, .net, dll, visual-studio-2013

I try to develop a simple dll with System.Windows.Forms reference on vs.net 2013 express.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms171830.aspx

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
// Pull model smart tag example. 
// Need references to System.dll, System.Windows.Forms.dll,  
// System.Design.dll, and System.Drawing.dll. 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
```

Until this vs.net version, I usually right click References in SolutionExplorer and `Add Reference` and find System.Windows.Forms;

However, I could not find System.Windows.Forms anymore.

What do I miss? First of all, I simply need to create DLL on 64 bit-windows box. No Phone, no store, and it's not clear which template I start with.

If this is because of limitation of express version, please tell me so.
I will install the higher edition since I have MSDN.

Thanks.

PS. I could do this in express edition of the prior versions of vs.net (2010, 2012). Is the situation changes??

Comment: You installed the wrong version of VS Express...

Comment: What edition of VS 2013 Express do you use? You can see it in the title bar of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you installed the wrong [edition](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) of Express. You probably installed "Express 2013 for Windows", which is strictly for building Windows Phone and Windows Store apps. (Yes, the naming is confusing. It's because they're really trying to steer people toward creating Store apps.)

Instead, you need "Express 2013 for Windows **Desktop**".

Comment: I see. You are right. What a messy confusion they made. I have started  using VisualStudio.net since version 1, but the experience recently got worse I think. Anyway I am installing ultimate now. thanks a lot.